# Setting up quotas for 50K+ home directories

Tags: windows-server-2008, quota

I have a windows 2008 R2 volume which is organized like this (because of the high number of directories):

`E:\{first_letter}\{login}`

I have enabled Windows FSRM to apply quotas to E:\, with the auto-apply option.

However, it seems that the quota is applied on the intermediate folder (E:{first_letter}) which means the quota is shared by all users in the intermediate folder.

Does the FSRM GUI have an option for situations like this or do I have to generate a quota for each intermediate folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to createa quota for every intermediate folder, sorry. THis is not a supported scenario withou that interim manual steop.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that this can be done via Powershell

Something like this http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/33839299/modifying-a-disk-quota-entry.aspx